# finding the number of possible decodings of the given number(dynamic programming)

Tags: c++, encryption, permutation, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a problem where every letter has a respective number such as a-1,b-2....z-26.
Now given a number, **in how many ways can the number be decoded is the question**. consider an example where 25114 can be decoded as 'BEAN',‘BEAAD’, ‘YAAD’, ‘YAN’, ‘YKD’ and ‘BEKD’. this could be decoded in 6 ways.
I have written code in c++ but I am getting the wrong answer. Please correct my code.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int total = 0;
int arr[100001];
void func(int start,int end,int factor){
    if(start==end)
        return;
    int j =start;
    if(factor==2&&j==end-1)//if j is the last element and factor is 2,accessing j+1 element is illegual
        return;
    if(factor==2){
        if((arr[j]*10+arr[j+1])>26)
            return;
        else{
            total++;
            func(start+2,end,1);
            func(start+2,end,2);
        }
    }
    else{//factor is 1
    total++;
    func(start+1,end,1);
    func(start+1,end,2);
    }
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int p;
        cin>>p;
        arr[i]=p;
    }
    func(0,n,1);
    func(0,n,2);
    cout<<total<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

essentially what my code is doing is that it fixes one number from the given array(using one digit or two digits from the the given array) and recurses until all the combinations are covered. for example considering the above case, I first choose '2' as my first digit and decode it as 'B'(factor = 1) and then choose '25' and decode it as 'E'(factor = 2).
**following are the input and output from the following code
input : 25114
expected output : 6
my output :  15
input : 3333333333(10 digits)
expected output :  1
my output : 10

Comment: For this kind of an algorithm I will expect exactly one call to the recursive function from `main()`, not two. Didn't bother to pick apart the recursive function's code to see exactly what it tries to do (and what it doesn't try to do), but the erroneous duplicate call to the recursive function sufficiently indicates that the proposed approach appears to be fundamentally flawed, and should be scrapped and reimplemented from scratch. Additionally, variable-length arrays are non-standard C++. You will get much more benefit from a good C++ book, than from these kinds of puzzles.

Comment: Plese [edit] your question and explain what exactly means "I am getting the wrong answer". What input do you use, what output do you actually get and what do you want to get.

Comment: @Bodo I am sorry, I have edited the post and included two inputs and outputs along with expected output. Please look into the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Based on the original program from the question I suggest to count the encodings when you reach the end only (`if(start==end)`).

As `func` will always be called twice with `factor=1` and `factor=2`, I can freely choose either condition for counting.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int total = 0;
int arr[100001];
void func(int start,int end,int factor){
    if(start==end) {
        if(factor == 1) total++; // count once when reaching the end 
        return;
    }
    int j =start;
    if((factor==2) && (j==end-1))//if j is the last element and factor is 2,accessing j+1 element is illegal
        return;
    if(factor==2){
        if((arr[j]*10+arr[j+1])>26)
            return;
        else{
            //total++;
            func(start+2,end,1);
            func(start+2,end,2);
        }
    }
    else{//factor is 1
        //total++;
        func(start+1,end,1);
        func(start+1,end,2);
    }
    return;
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int p;
        cin>>p;
        arr[i]=p;
    }
    func(0,n,1);
    func(0,n,2);
    cout<<total<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This calculates the expected results from the example input in the question.

```
$ echo 5 2 5 1 1 4|./program
6
$ echo 10 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3|./program
1
```

There is room for improvement.

Instead of modifying a global variable I would return the number of combinations from `func` and add the values in the higher level.

I would also handle the distinction between 2-digit and 1-digit numbers in the **called** `func` instead of in the caller.

Something like this pseudo code:

```
int func(int start, int end)
{
    if(remaining length is <2) {
        // we reached the end, so this is one combination
        return 1;
    }
    if(two-digit number is >26) {
        // only a 1-digit number is possible, count remaining combinations
        return func(start+1, end);
    }
    // both a 1-digit or 2-digit number is possible, add the remaining combinations for both cases
    return func(start+1) + func(start+2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged as "dynamic-programming", but it is anything but.
Instead, think about the state space and its boundary conditions:

- The empty string has zero encodings;
- A single digit has a single encoding;
- An n-digit string has as many encodings as an (n-1)-digit substring plus as many encodings as an (n-2)-digit substring if the first two digits are <= 26.

Thus, we can walk the string from back to front and store the intermediate results for reuse:

```
uint64_t solve(std::vector<int>& digits) {
    const int n = digits.size();
    std::vector<int> encodings(n+1);
    encodings[n] = 1;
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        bool two_digits_fit = (i < n - 1) && (digits[i] * 10 + digits[i+1]) <= 26; // What if digits[i] == 0?
        encodings[i] = encodings[i+1] + (two_digits_fit ? encodings[i+2] : 0);
    }
    return encodings[0];
}
```